# Does Ruby have command to format the screen like QBASIC?

Tags: ruby, qbasic

**QBASIC** have some commands, such as **LOCATE (x, y)** that place the cursor at certain location on the screen, and **CLS** that clears the screen, which help a console application look clean.

Does ruby have the same functionality? It could be nice to use it for a small project.

Thanks for helping

Comment: You don't really want to do this - there is no cross-platform solutions for the problem and unless you are developing some console UI for real application there is no practical use.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. In fact, it's just a class project and ruby is something we're learning. We don't want to spend to much time with a GUI library. That's why I asked about that functionnality because it makes the screen cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

No, but look up ncurses.
http://ncurses-ruby.berlios.de/

Comment: In the link you provided, they are talking about C, Linux,.. I've a laptop running on Windows. Is the library still gonna work?

Comment: Don't know, but try this link http://roguebasin.roguelikedevelopment.org/index.php/Ruby#ncurses-ruby

Answer (score 1):

You can clear the screen with `system "clear"`, and print the whole screen each time.